# How to append string to API url onclick in React js

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to append a string to all url when I click on a button, how to do this ?

Here is the code 
App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from './Button';

let API = 'https://someurl.com/';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      results: []
    };
    this.updateUrl = this.updateUrl.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(API);
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ 
      results: json.results 
    });
  };


  updateButton = (event) => {
     this.setState({ 
      API.concat('?format=fzjeozfij')
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button data={this.state} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Button.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    const updateButton = this.props.data;
    return (
      <button type="button" onClick={updateButton}>Button</button>
    )
  }
}

export default Button;
```

My goal is to get the url from `const API` to https://someurl.com/?format=zegizhgz
I think I have to modify the fetchData function to concat some string to the url but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: is this what you want ? 

const response = await fetch(`${API}?format=fzjeozfij`);

Comment: I want '?format=blabla' to be added when I trigger `updateButton` function by clicking on the button

Comment: could you please try the following

`updateButton = (event) => {
const api=`  ${API}?format=fzjeozfij`
     this.setState({ 
    api
    });
  }`

Comment: it gets me the error `Syntax error: src/component/App.js: Unexpected token, expected ; (50:16)`

Comment: and on the fetch data read the state as the following 
await fetch(this.state.api);

Comment: `updateButton = (event) => {
    const api= ${API}'?format=wookiee';
    this.setState({ api }); 
  }`
Still gets me unexpected token, did I write it wrong ?

Comment: i use backticks which is ` not '

Comment: please write it as the following  const api= \`${API}?format=wookiee\`

Comment: still the same error

Comment: i will write the code on the answer so that i can show it well

Comment: is this a compile error or runtime error ?

Comment: runtime I guess, it appears both at load and when I click on the button, but the app still is rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  updateButton = () => {
  const nApi = `${this.state.api}?format=wookiee`;
this.setState({ api: nApi });

  this.fetchData(nApi);
      }
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Button onClick={this.updateButton}/>
          </div>
        );
      }

     fetchData = async (api) => {
        const response = await fetch(api);
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({ 
          results: json.results 
        });
      };
```

Button.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    const {onClick} = this.props;
    return (
      <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>Button</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error : Uncaught Invariant Violation: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.

Comment: I uploaded my current code here https://jsfiddle.net/yqL9r4zt/
No error but no rerender of the data

Comment: @Matt355 pleace have a look on this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vonflf , i put some remarks on code and removed the list tag as i do not have its file , it now render the button on the view

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, it gets me the error `Unexpected token w in JSON at fetchData = async (api) => {`

Comment: Ok, the json I'm targetting has a parse error, so it works (in a way) thanks